# Uploading a photo to parse.com through Corona

Tags: file, lua, parse-platform, coronasdk

I have this code which should be almost there to upload a file to my class in parse.com. i cant get the right syntax for this line in my code below    message1["photo"] = {"name"=urladress, "__type": "File"},.

```
message = {}
local function networkListener2( event )
    print (event.response)
end
local function sendresponse( event )
print (event.response)
     local urladress = '{ "results": [ '
     tables1 = urladress..string.sub(event.response, 0,-2)..'] }'
        urladress = json.decode (tables1)
        print (urladress.results[1].url)

        headers = {}
        headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = APPID
        headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = RESTAPIKEY
         headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

        local params = {}   
        params.headers = headers
        local message1 = {}
        message1["name"] = "Andrew"
        message1["photo"] = {"name"=urladress, "__type": "File"},
         params.body = json.encode ( message1 )
 network.request( "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/photos", "POST", networkListener2,  params)
end

local saverecord = function(  )
  headers = {}
        headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = APPID
        headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = RESTAPIKEY
        headers["Content-Type"] = "image/jpeg"
        local params = {}
        params.headers = headers
        params.bodyType = "binary"
network.upload("https://api.parse.com/1/files/photo.jpg","POST",sendresponse,params,"photo.jpg",system.DocumentsDirectory,"image/jpeg")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indirect upload which gives you a url and work with that. such as

```
 local function onPhotoUpload( event )
     local dataTable = { ["photo"] = event.response.url }
  end
 parse:uploadFile( { ["filename"] = "image.jpg", ["baseDir"] = system.DocumentsDirectory }, onPhotoUpload )
```

Answer (score 0):

`parse` doesn't support direct file upload.